# usual eigenvectors are not the same generalized eigenvectors with identiity matrix using eigh in python

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, python

I have a matrix A= array([[ 5.25611770e+01, -1.52618366e-01,  2.96790052e+01,
        -6.18890493e+01],
       [-1.52618366e-01,  9.22957306e+00, -3.18143330e+00,
         3.18998264e+01],
       [ 2.96790052e+01, -3.18143330e+00,  4.98805057e+01,
         2.06257296e+01],
       [-6.18890493e+01,  3.18998264e+01,  2.06257296e+01,
         3.38531289e+03]])

in python, their eigenvectors using scipy.linalg.eigh(A) are:

[[ 0.13131632  0.68589019  0.71551958  0.01850384]
 [-0.97577162  0.21673083 -0.02843274 -0.00943735]
 [-0.17454149 -0.69452338  0.69795162 -0.0060059 ]
 [ 0.0126898   0.01482094  0.00931854 -0.99976621]]

And using scipy.linalg.eigh(A,Id) that is the generalized eigenvalue problem with the identity, their eigenvectors must be the same that scipy.linalg.eigh(A), but they are:

[[ 0.13131632  0.68589019  0.71551958 -0.01850384]
 [-0.97577162  0.21673083 -0.02843274  0.00943735]
 [-0.17454149 -0.69452338  0.69795162  0.0060059 ]
 [ 0.0126898   0.01482094  0.00931854  0.99976621]]

Note the last column.

Comment: Why must they be the same?

Comment: The problem Av=rA is equal to the generalized problem Av=rBv when B is the Identity

Comment: You do remember that eigenvectors are not unique? What reason do you have to believe that this scipy function that you’re asking about will return exactly the same values given different, albeit mathematically equivalent, inputs? Is there some claim in its documentation to that effect?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the last one was just flipped in its sign?

Note that if $\mathbf q$ is an eigenvector, so is $-\mathbf q$ since $\mathbf A \mathbf q = \lambda \mathbf q \; \Leftrightarrow \; \mathbf A (-\mathbf q) = \lambda (-\mathbf q)$. In other words, the sign of the eigenvector is not determined.

Comment: Excellent point. Moreover, if $\mathbf q$ is an eigenvector, so is $\alpha\mathbf q$, for any $\alpha$.

Comment: True, its norm is not determined either. It's common for software like scipy to spit them out as unit-norm but that's just a convention.